# Facilitate SQL table query functionality in Java application

Tags: java, sql, data-structures

Say I have a couple of columns say **First Name, LastName, Email, Phone**.

I want to query for a row based on a dynamic column selection.

Say the application will ask for a record based on 1) lastname and phone or 2) FirstName 3) Phone and Email

Instead of creating a table to do a SQL query to find a row based on the column data is there a data structure which suits my needs? **I am coding in Java, so if there is an inbuilt API please suggest one**

```
FirstName | LastName | Email     | Phone
abc       | xyz      | abc@m.com | 123
pqr       | qwe      | pqr@m.com | 342
ijk       | uio      | ijk@m.com | 987
```

Comment: You want to use where statements? Or do you just want a set of columns?

Comment: I dont want to do a sql stmt. Based on dynamic column selection I want a record returned. I'm parsing a file I dont know which columns will have data. I want to get a best shot of find a record with available information from the file.

Comment: So your basically looking for which row has a column with an entry your looking for?

Comment: You could use a HashMap that has as Key the words, and contains another data structure for locations. Example in answer.

Comment: By "an inbuilt API", I assume you mean something along the lines of "this functionality in the standard API". Because there's only one "inbuilt" Java API.

Comment: Appreciate a constructive criticism. Editing my question based on what has been commented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd point you to any of the available in memory SQL Db libraries:

1. H2
2. Derby
3. HSQL

Or maybe you want an indexable, queryable in-memory store:

1. Hazelcast
2. Ehcache

Any one of these allows you to write a query against the data stored.

Comment: The phrasing in the question might be somewhat ambiguous, but OP doesn't appear to be asking for an external library. If it were, it would be off topic, which leads me to the conclusion that this *answer* isn't in line with [so] guidelines.

Comment: Actually, the problem is in the phrasing of the original question which misled the original answerer. As a minimum it should be "fascilitate SQL table query functionallity", and more specifically the basic requirement as admitted by the OP is "looking for which row has a column with a search value".

Comment: Actually I would disagree. OP has clearly asked for an answer to a question wherein there are many well-known and already solved libraries which can do exactly what he wants. If I asked a question and someone presented me with an alternative and less error prone solution, I'd be thankful.

Comment: There *are* many libraries that already does what OP wants, but asking for such a library is off topic for [so] and, presumably for the same reasons, answers that suggest such libraries (as the main part of the answer) to questions not explicitly asking for such libraries are not appropriate. Whether or not OP would be thankful doesn't affect whether or not it's appropriate. I think it would likely fit as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the information loaded into memory and available for multiple queries, I would use a lookup structure using a Map (e.g. a HashMap) and ArrayList.

*Note: If your only going to query once, I would do it directly in the look when reading the lines.*

EG: `HashMap<String, ArrayList<wordLocation>> lookup= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<wordLocation>>();`

**Example:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordLookup {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        WordLookup wl = new WordLookup();

        String[] simulatedFileRows = new String[5];
        simulatedFileRows[0] = "cat,dog";
        simulatedFileRows[1] = "hen,dog";
        simulatedFileRows[2] = "cat,mouse";
        simulatedFileRows[3] = "moose,squirrel";
        simulatedFileRows[4] = "chicken,rabbit";

        String columns[];
        String row;
        int column = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<simulatedFileRows.length; i++)   //Simulated readline
        {
            row = simulatedFileRows[i];
            columns = row.split(",");
            column=0;

            for(String col:columns)
            {
                column++;
                wl.addWord(col, i, column);
            }
        }


        //Where is moose?

        ArrayList<wordLocation> locs = wl.getWord("moose");
        if(locs!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("Moose found at:");
            for(wordLocation loc: locs)
            System.out.println("\t line:"+ loc.line + " column" + loc.column);
        }


    }

    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<wordLocation>> lookup= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<wordLocation>>();

    public void addWord(String word, int line, int column)
    {
        ArrayList<wordLocation> wordLocArr = lookup.get(word);
        if(wordLocArr == null)
        {
            wordLocArr = new ArrayList<wordLocation>();
            lookup.put(word,wordLocArr);
        }

        wordLocArr.add( new wordLocation(line, column));
    }

    public ArrayList<wordLocation> getWord(String word)
    {
        return lookup.get(word);
    }

    class wordLocation{
        public int line, column;

        public wordLocation(int l, int c)
        {this.line = l; this.column = c;}
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have something like HashMap map for field=>value
then you can do (if you dont want to query with value, you can take out the where statement)

```
if(map.size()>0){
String whereStatement = " 1=1 ";
String selectStatement = " ";
for(String field : map.keySet()){
    whereStatement+= " AND "+ field+"="+map.get(field);
    selectStatement+= field+",";
}
selectStatement.replaceLast(",", "");

String query = "SELECT " + selectStatement + " FROM sometable " + whereStatement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't index the columns in an SQL DB, that's roughly equivalent to simply having an array, where each element corresponds to a row.

If you do index the columns, that's about the same as additionally having something like a `TreeMap` (of string or integer or some collection of objects, depending on the type of the fields, to array index) for each index (at least based on my somewhat limited knowledge of the underlying structure of DBs - actually I think databases typically use [b-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), but there isn't a b-tree structure in the standard Java API to my knowledge).

Actually a `TreeMap` to array index isn't sufficient for non-unique indices, you'll have to have a `TreeMap` to *a list* of array indices, or a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) (not in the standard API).

If you don't have an index for any given query, you'll have to iterate through all the rows to find the correct one. Similarly, you'll have to iterate through the whole array to find the correct element.

So, if you only want to query single columns (and do so efficiently), and this can be any of the columns, you'll have to have a `TreeMap` (or similar) for each column, and an array or similar as a base structure.

If, however, we're talking about querying any combination of columns, you're unlikely to get a particularly efficient generic solution, as there would simply be too many combinations to have a structure for all of them, even for a small number of columns.

**Note:** I say `TreeMap` as opposed to `HashMap`, as this is closer to how databases actually work. If the types of queries you're running doesn't require sorted data, you could happily use a `HashMap` instead.